# Does $\inf_{(a,b)\in A} ax+by=\inf_{(a,b)\in B} ax+by$ imply $A=B$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $A,B\subseteq\Bbb [0,1]\times [0,1]$, and for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$ with $x^2+y^2=1$,
$$\inf_{(a,b)\in A} ax+by=\inf_{(a,b)\in B} ax+by$$
Can we deduce $\overline A=\overline B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ax+by$ is the dot product of $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$. So
$ax+by = (a,b).(x,y) = |(x,y)||(a,b)|\cos (\theta) = |(a,b)|\cos(\theta)$

As a counter example let $A$ be the unit circle and $B$ be the unit square with the open disc removed $\{(a,b)| a^2+b^2 \ge1\}$

Then the inf will be the same for both, $0, \forall x,y$.

Comment: Hi @pipie314, welcome to Math.SE! Unfotunately It's not possible to understand what you meant. Are $A$ and $B$ the sets described above by @CutieKrait? You could explain better your argument and try to use latex in your answers/questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 5):

My intuition suggests that geometrically these conditions should be equivalent to that the closed convex hulls of $A$ and $B$ coincide.